# jQuery функция по очистке определенного input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно очистить определенное поле по нажатию на кнопку?

```
$('body').on('click', '.my-clean', function () {
    $('#documentrepairs-id_counterparties').val('');
    console.log("Input очищен");
});
```

У меня уже есть вот такой код, но он чистит только то поле, которое указанно в качестве `id`. Меня интересует более универсальный вариант.
Например, кнопок на странице может быть несколько как и самих полей. На мой взгляд, постоянно прописывать данные значения для каждой кнопки не целесообразно. Так же, я хотел бы этот код вынести в отдельный пакет JS, чтоб еще раз показывать что данный код тут не уместен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.my-clean', function () {
  $(this).closest("div").find("input").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="some value"/><button class="my-clean">Clear</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="some other value"/><button class="my-clean">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Игорь вы гений! Не очень я селен в js и все с ним связанное)))

Comment: @МаксимСычевский Ну что Вы! Не стоит.